# Android Studio GeoDataClient and PlaceDetectionClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-maps

I know `GeoDataClient` can be import by adding `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places'` in `build.gradle`.

But Google say "`'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places'`is deprecated".
So we have to use `'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'`.

By the way `'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'` doesn't contain `GeoDataClient` and `PlaceDetectionClient`.

How could I resolve those two objects?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fuckingtest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: You can check the migration guide to find some answers : https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: @cesarmarch   Thank you man.  I LOVE U

Answer (score 0):

add to `dependencies` in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

Comment: More structural information required to fit your answer as a solution. Please edit.